# Linq to SQL if statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
var PAS =
        (from v in dc.PAS
            where
            days.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(v.fecha))
            group v.valor by new { v.entidad_id, v.modulo_id, v.peticion_id, v.hora_id, v.dia_id } into hg
            orderby hg.Key.entidad_id descending, hg.Key.peticion_id ascending, hg.Key.hora_id descending
            select new
            {
                Hora = hg.Key.hora_id,
                Dia = hg.Key.dia_id,
                Entidad = hg.Key.entidad_id,
                Modulo = hg.Key.modulo_id,
                Peticion = hg.Key.peticion_id,
                Media = Math.Round(System.Convert.ToDouble(hg.Average()), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
            };
```

Then do a foreach, and insert a new row for each result into another table with this new values... (Because I can't bulk, at least I don't know how to in LINQ)

I have three `v.peticion_id` possible values...  I want to get two '`Media`' columns, one with the actual media, and another one just with `v.peticion_id = 0` value... I can't explain better so here is an example of what I want to get...

```
Hora  |  Dia  |  Entidad  |  Modulo  |  Peticion  |  Media  |  Media2
  0       0         0          0           0         333.3  |  333.3
  0       0         0          0           1         4.4    |  333.3
  0       0         0          0           2         0.7    |  333.3
  1       0         0          0           0         178.2  |  178.2
  1       0         0          0           1         1.8    |  178.2
  1       0         0          0           2         0      |  178.2
```

I hope someone can help me..

Comment: First group without `peticion_id`, calculate `Media2` with condition `peticion_id == 0`, then group these data by `peticion_id` and calculate averages.

Comment: Can you write an example code?? I don't know how to group by with `peticion_id == 0` condition and then group by `peticion_id` in the same query... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just select `v.peticion_id == 0`

Or am I missunderstanding what you want to do here?

Comment: If I do that I will only get results for peticion_id == 0, but I want to get 0, 1 and 2, but column Media2 just the average for peticion_id == 0

Comment: Sorry @user1381537 but I have no clue as to what you mean. Can you try to explain a bit more?